# Windows 8.1 BitmapImage to Byte array or a stream

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm trying to convert a BitmapImage to a byte array or a stream in WinRT 8.1. This was straightforward in Windows 8, since the WriteableBitmap could be created using a BitmapImage, but is no longer so in 8.1. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this in 8.1?

Regards,

Dmitri

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use BitmapImage over something like WriteableBitmap? Is it just so that you can set the source via Uri?

Comment: The BitmapImage gets handed to me from a different part of the application, the toolkit that I'm using expects a Stream.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it was possible in Windows 8, but WinRT XAML Toolkit had [some support](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.cs) for a while to load a `WriteableBitmap` based on a `BitmapImage`, but it actually tries to load it from the same source as the original BI. There is no way to access the pixels of a BI itself, so if you expect to be doing that - start off with a `WriteableBitmap` in the first place.